# Change US visa interview location

Tags: visas, usa, visa-renewals

I filled in and submitted a DS 160 electronic application form, where I selected Abuja as the interview location.

When booking my appointment, I realised that the first available date was 10 days after I required to be in the U.S. So, I checked the US consulate in Lagos and discovered that there were available dates that were convenient for my travel plan, so I chose one of those dates.

Would this limit my chances of getting my visa renewed?

Answer (score 1):

In theory this should have no affect on the decision. Many people have changed their interview locations before and still been issued a visa.

If they’re really curious, you can just explain the situation. As long as you still meet all the requirements you should have no problem.